# Debian Stable with one install ever

Tags: debian, system-installation

Please this is not duplicate in this entire universe .

After a lot research on distros I got more confused. I was happily living with my lubuntu and `apt-get` for years. Then I came across a system format and my digging started. Finally I arrived to Debian stable.

**Now if I install Debian 7 stable and there happens to be a release of Debian 8 stable,
would I be able to switch it without booting installing any other distro?
I really do not want to go to testing or unstable.**
So one line my purpose is to fully avoid reinstall nix system after a year or two.

My purpose is simple programming. I heard about arch, but I have not much time to get deep learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian aims to release a new stable every two years.  The old stable continues to receive security updates for a year after the new stable is released.  So, if your timing is right, you can go three years between major upgrades.

Generally one can upgrade from one stable to the next in a few simple steps and one reboot.  It need happen only once every couple years.  So, it is not a major burden.

As an example, Debian's current stable ("Wheezy", 7), was released May 2013.  So, if all goes according to plan, the next stable ("Jessie", 8) will be released somewhere around May, 2015, and Wheezy will continue to receive security updates through May 2016.

You can read more about Debian's release policy [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases).

Comment: thanks , you save my life, i read out tha already, means i just install debian 7.3, then after two year ,there will be debian [?????] 8.
and i have to only change source and update and i good to go, I know some risk in that process , but its cool na